# Setting a point using GDAL WFS-T tinyows

Tags: gdal, postgresql, wfs, ogr

I’m trying to set a point xyz, which represents longitude altitude latitude, but when I create the feature, I get error:

> Error 1 Can’t find transcation response.

The Geometry field is set by this in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE poiserver ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POINTZ,4326) USING ST_Force3D(geom);


OGRLayer *poLayer; 
    poLayer = m_wfs_t->GetLayerByName("tows:poiserver");

    OGRFeature *poFeature;        


    poFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature( poLayer->GetLayerDefn() );
    poFeature->SetField( "name", "ahmed" ); 


    OGRPoint pt;        
    pt.setX( 120 );        
    pt.setY( 240 );
    pt.setZ(10);

    poFeature->SetGeometry( &pt );          

    if( poLayer->CreateFeature( poFeature ) != OGRERR_NONE ) 
    {
        std::cout <<"error creating a feature"<<endl;

    }

    OGRFeature::DestroyFeature( poFeature );
```

Comment: Where and how are you creating the feature?

Comment: I have updated my post including the code, please take a look